# Think in database or Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I'm new in Hibernate and came across several problems when designing relationships from database to Hibernate code generation. I prefer to use foreign key constraints to design one-one, one-to-many, many-to-many relationships,as it's more intuitive and clear. But when using DB-Browser to generate code, I found relationships are messed up, and I have to do lots of manual rewriting to xml to get desired relationships. If table changes, that might be difficult to maintain consistency between database and Hibernate.

Can you give me some advice to bridge the gap between database design to OOP? Maybe there are different approaches, e.g., some of guys I know do not design relationships in database with constraints but rely on xml in Hibernate to define relationship. **In other words, relationships in Hiberate are (partially) independent of database?**

Many thanks.

Comment: If the integral database design (the internal database structure) itself is changed (infrequently), then it is often not independent of the rest of the environment (recall Logical Data Independence in DBMS which is always difficult to achieve). It is not only constrained to Hibernate or any other ORMs but the same thing will also happen, if you use plain JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

When using an ORM you have 3 "sources of truth" regarding your domain model:

- the database
- the mapping
- the classes

What you need to do is decide which 2 (two) of those 3 (three) you'll be managing, and have the third one auto generated.

I choose to create my own classes and the mapping, and let `hbm2ddl` generate the database for me. Whatever I want to make the database do I make sure I describe it correctly on the mapping (e.g keys, indexes, column lengths and constraints). And if I ever need to do something "custom" in my database I make sure I describe this with various hibernate constructs such as:

- database objects: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-database-object
- extending the dialect: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html
- usertypes: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html
- interceptors: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html
- etc

The end result is that a new developer can just checkout the code, run hbm2ddl "export" and start working on the project imediatelly being sure that his/her database schema is 100% the same as mine.

Answer (score 0):

If hibernate mapping in xml makes you sick check this: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/

In my opinion, annotations are much more clean and can be easly refactored.

Comment: yes, I want low-level control of database. Annotations may be the correct way in my case. thanks.